# autoStartup for @StreamListener

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Unlike `@KafkaListener`, it looks like `@StreamListener` does not support the `autoStartup` parameter.  Is there a way to achieve this same behavior for `@StreamListener`?  Here's my use case:

I have a generic Spring application that can listen to any Kafka topic and write to its corresponding table in my database.  For some topics, the volume is low and thus processing a single message with very low latency is fine.  For other topics that are high volume, the code should receive a microbatch of messages and write to the database using Jdbc batch on a less frequent basis. Ideally the definition for the listeners would look something like this:

```
// low volume listener
@StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT, autoStartup="${application.singleMessageListenerEnabled}")
public void handleSingleMessage(@Payload GenericRecord message) ...

// high volume listener
@StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT, autoStartup="${application.multipleMessageListenerEnabled}")
public void handleMultipleMessages(@Payload List<GenericRecord> messageList) ...
```

For a low-volume topic, I would set `application.singleMessageListenerEnabled` to **true** and `application.multipleMessageListenerEnabled` to **false**, and vice versa for a high-volume topic. Thus, only one of the listeners would be actively listening for messages and the other not actively listening.

Is there a way to achieve this with `@StreamListener`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please consider upgrading to [functional programming model](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_cloud_function) which would take you minutes to refactor. We've all but deprecated the annotation-based programming model.
If you do then what you're trying to accomplish is very easy:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SimpleStreamApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SimpleStreamApplication.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<GenericRecord> singleRecordConsumer() {...}

    @Bean
    public Consumer<List<GenericRecord>> multipleRecordConsumer() {...}
}
```

Then you can simply use `--spring.cloud.function.definition=singleRecordConsumer` property for a single case and `--spring.cloud.function.definition=multipleRecordConsumer` when starting the application, this ensuring which specific listener you want to activate.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  I was able to get the singleRecordConsumer working fine.  However, I would like to be able to get the Kafka headers but couldn't figure out a way to do that.

For multipleRecordConsumer, I got the code below to compile but it doesn't receive any messages.  I added the following to my application.properties file.


`spring.cloud.function.definition=multipleRecordConsumer
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.multipleRecordConsumer-in-0.consumer.batch-mode=true`

Comment: ```class KeyValuePair {
        protected GenericRecord key;
        protected GenericRecord value;
        public KeyValuePair(GenericRecord key, GenericRecord value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<KStream<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>> singleRecordConsumer() {
        return stream -> stream.foreach((key, value) -> {
            log.debug("singleRecordConsumer: key={}, value={}", key, value);
        });
    }```

Comment: ```@Bean
public Consumer<KTable<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>> multipleRecordConsumer() {
  return records -> {
    KStream<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> stream = records.toStream();
    List<KeyValuePair> microbatch = new ArrayList<>();
    stream.foreach((key, value) -> {
      microbatch.add(new KeyValuePair(key, value));
    });
    log.debug("multipleRecordConsumer: microbatch record count={}", microbatch.size());
    for (KeyValuePair keyValuePair : microbatch) {
      log.debug("multipleRecordConsumer: key={}, value={}", keyValuePair.key, keyValuePair.value);
    }
 };
}```